# Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifer, also Anonymous Function Error

Tags: javascript, eval, anonymous-function

I am getting a `Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier` in the Chrome Console Window. The lines are below, I have just posted a snippet of the function, the entire function can be found on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9T2J/).

```
var shipping_price = $(".shipping_price").html();
shipping_price = shipping_price.substring(1, shipping_price.length);
$('input[name="shipping_price"]').val(shipping_price); // Update our Hidden Field

// Unexpected Identifier
result += eval(shipping_price); // This is where Im getting the error
```

I have to use eval otherwise the function does not work. I am also getting an error when I call the [above function](http://jsfiddle.net/j9T2J/):

```
// Call getTotalPrice(); On DOM Ready
// dom ready
getTotalPrice(); // Anonymous function error, I think this is fixed when I fix the above error.
```

Any ideas how I can fix these easily?

Comment: Why are you `eval`ing `shipping_price`? Id it because you want them to be able to enter `3*5`? That's not reason enough. You should never `eval` user input blindly.

Comment: What is the value of `shipping_price`? Anyway, I suspect that you want to use `parseFloat` rather than `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var shipping_price = $(".shipping_price").html();
shipping_price = shipping_price.substring(1); //unless your removing the dollar sign from the string, you should start on 0, not 1.. which would mean you dont need substring at all.
$('input[name="shipping_price"]').val(shipping_price); // Update our Hidden Field

result += Number(shipping_price);
```

also, Anonymous function error means that the function does not exist, check capitalization and spelling

Comment: Then your $(".shipping_price").html() contains something other than a number. ex:  "123 76" will return NaN.   but "12376" will return 12376

Comment: put this in the code and see what u get alert("-"+$(".shipping_price").html()+"-");
you should get a dash+number+dash result

Comment: then change the 0 back to 1 in the substring line of code and it will work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

1. In `.substring`, you can omit the second parameter if you want all characters from a specified position to the end.
2. Never use `eval`. It seems you're converting a string into a number. `parseFloat` is what you want.

E.g.

```
var shipping_price = $(".shipping_price").html();
shipping_price = shipping_price.substring(1);
$('input[name="shipping_price"]').val(shipping_price);

result += parseFloat(shipping_price);
```